# How to put two href links in an If statement?

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

If the request is authenticated I want the login and create account link to appear as "Login/Create Account" both as links to their relevant pages.

I'm getting an error in the else section. How do I re-write this to get rid of the error and display the links how I want it?

```
 <div class="float-right">
                <div class="user-option">
                    <span class="icon icon-avatar"></span>
                    @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        <a href="/account/logout">Logout</a>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                   <a href="/account/login">Login</a>  /  <a href = "/account/create-account" > Signup </a>;

                    }


                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you have is the froward slash. It is not inside any html tag.A quick fix is to wrap it in a span.

```
    <a href="/account/login">Login</a> <span>/</span> <a href = "/account/create-account"> Signup </a>
```

A more correct way would be to place your links in an un-ordered list and use CSS to format them.